# how to cluster wso2am-analytics-2.0.0

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2-das

We are building wso2am in cluster mode. 
 Is there any document about building wso2am-analytics cluster ?
 I have tried to use wso2das, reference as below.
https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS310/Working+with+Product+Specific+Analytics+Profiles

## But get the error as below

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-12-09 15:00:00,101] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.spark.core.AnalyticsTask} -  Error while executing the scheduled task for the script: APIM_LATENCY_BREAKDOWN_STATS {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.spark.core.AnalyticsTask}
org.wso2.carbon.analytics.spark.core.exception.AnalyticsExecutionException: Exception in executing query CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE APIMGT_PERHOUR_EXECUTION_TIME USING CarbonAnalytics OPTIONS(tableName "ORG_WSO2_APIMGT_STATISTICS_PERHOUREXECUTIONTIMES", schema "    year INT -i, month INT -i, day INT -i, hour INT -i, context STRING, api_version STRING, api STRING, tenantDomain STRING,    apiPublisher STRING, apiResponseTime DOUBLE, securityLatency DOUBLE, throttlingLatency DOUBLE, requestMediationLatency DOUBLE, responseMediationLatency DOUBLE,    backendLatency DOUBLE, otherLatency DOUBLE, firstEventTime LONG, _timestamp LONG -i",    primaryKeys "year, month, day, hour, context, api_version, tenantDomain, apiPublisher",    incrementalProcessing "APIMGT_PERHOUR_EXECUTION_TIME, DAY",    mergeSchema "false")
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.spark.core.internal.SparkAnalyticsExecutor.executeQueryLocal(SparkAnalyticsExecutor.java:764)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.spark.core.internal.SparkAnalyticsExecutor.executeQuery(SparkAnalyticsExecutor.java:721)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.spark.core.CarbonAnalyticsProcessorService.executeQuery(CarbonAnalyticsProcessorService.java:201)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.spark.core.CarbonAnalyticsProcessorService.executeScript(CarbonAnalyticsProcessorService.java:151)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.spark.core.AnalyticsTask.execute(AnalyticsTask.java:60)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ntask.core.impl.TaskQuartzJobAdapter.execute(TaskQuartzJobAdapter.java:67)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown options : incrementalprocessing
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.spark.core.sources.AnalyticsRelationProvider.checkParameters(AnalyticsRelationProvider.java:123)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.spark.core.sources.AnalyticsRelationProvider.setParameters(AnalyticsRelationProvider.java:113)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.spark.core.sources.AnalyticsRelationProvider.createRelation(AnalyticsRelationProvider.java:75)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.spark.core.sources.AnalyticsRelationProvider.createRelation(AnalyticsRelationProvider.java:45)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:158)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.CreateTempTableUsing.run(ddl.scala:92)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.doExecute(commands.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:132)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:130)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:130)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:55)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:55)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.<init>(DataFrame.scala:145)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.<init>(DataFrame.scala:130)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$.apply(DataFrame.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:817)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.spark.core.internal.SparkAnalyticsExecutor.executeQueryLocal(SparkAnalyticsExecutor.java:760)
        ... 11 more
```

======================================================

Any suggestion will be appreciated !!

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear of what you are asking. Are you using DAS or the wso2am-analytics that's shipped along the wso2am-2.0.0?

If you are using wso2am-2.0.0 along with the wso2das-3.1.0 then there is an issue with the spark analytics scripts that comes with the DAS.

This is due to the use of [incremental processing](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS310/Incremental+Processing). IncrementalProcessing should be changed to IncrementalParams.

You can see this has been fixed by wso2 [here](https://github.com/wso2/analytics-apim/pull/314/files), but has not been released yet.

You can update the scripts from the DAS carbon console under main/Batch Analytics/scripts

Comment: Tks alot, Im using wso2am-analytics.
Another question, is there any document about purge analytics data?
We need puge analytics data but keep summarized data in statdb.
According this docs https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM191/Publishing+API+Runtime+Statistics+Using+WSO2+DAS#PublishingAPIRuntimeStatisticsUsingWSO2DAS-PurgingData(optional)

Comment: What is your distribution and/or clustering pattern? Are you running wso2am-analytics as a single node along side wso2am-2.0.0 or is it clustered? Not really sure about the purging, sorry But if i recall right the data is by default kept for 2 weeks and then it's purged automatically.

Comment: Im running wso2am-analytics in HA mode according this docment https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Minimum+High+Availability+Deployment+-+DAS+3.0.1

After i ran load test, and the 'WSO2_ANALYTICS_EVENT_STORE_DB' db is growing about 500mb. So, is there any config can purge data to prevent run out disk sapce. Many thanks!!

Comment: Try this guide if you haven't. 

CAVEAT: Be careful so you only delete the tables you want. Haven't had the time to try this myself but i should do the trick

https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS310/Purging+Data#PurgingData-Globaldatapurging

Answer (score 0):

Tks for ur response!!  We need keeping summarized data in statdb,so which table should be purged ? I have found a link as below http://www.rukspot.com/Publishing_APIM_1100_Runtime_Statistics_to_DAS.html
It mentioned that just purge below table

ORG_WSO2_APIMGT_STATISTICS_DESTINATION

ORG_WSO2_APIMGT_STATISTICS_FAULT

ORG_WSO2_APIMGT_STATISTICS_REQUEST

ORG_WSO2_APIMGT_STATISTICS_RESPONSE

ORG_WSO2_APIMGT_STATISTICS_WORKFLOW

ORG_WSO2_APIMGT_STATISTICS_THROTTLE